# Making my apache localhost available over the internet

Tags: php, apache, localhost, remote-access, remote-server

I am using Ubuntu and have Apache server installed. I have a small php project that I want to demo to someone. I thought I could make it available over the internet, but I am not sur ehow to go about it. Can someone please list out the things I need to do  ( and if possible, why do I need to do that?)

The answers on the web are not really well structured and when I look at the comments sections, it says that the process never really worked for most of the people.

Thanks.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is server configuration/networking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would need to setup your router to allow access into your intranet. This can be done by forwarding a port. Usually you cant use port 80 on a home network connection and you need to use a different port to accomplish this.

Forward Port 8080 -> 80 on 192.168.0.15

Which means that when I goto 64.56.23.12:8080 through my web browser it will talk to my router, the router will then flip that port to 80 to the IP I designated.

Any changes to the config file will need a restart to fully reinstate.

... Now without any idea what your config file is, what internet company you have nor what your router model is I cant help you any further.

Basic Guide to Forwarding Ports -> [How to Geek - Forwarding Ports](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/)

---

When you input an IP address in a web browser what happens on the back end is the web browser will append port 80 on the end of the IP address (unless you specify a port). So if your WAN IP address is 64.64.54.54 and you try to access it the browser will add the following to the end 64.64.54.54:80. The problem occurs is while this message to find this server finally reaches your ISP it comes through their (router, firewall) that basically says "Nope, We Dont Allow Home Servers. This Port is Known for HTTP traffic.". What happens next can vary but essential its the same end result. You dont see your server.

To get around this you need to do whats called port forwarding. We tell our home router that I am expecting traffic on port 8080 and I want all traffic that arrives through port 8080 to goto this LAN IP address on this port. You can either change the port to forward to port 80 or stay the same to 8080.

Unfortunately ISP's dont like to give out unique IP addresses and even more so like to provision what is called NAT (Network Address Translation). So that 64.64.54.54 might change day to day, month to month or once a year. The other issue is NAT, your LAN IP address is under NAT (192.168.x.x). You can think of NAT as an Apartment Complex, everyone has the same address but different apartment numbers. With out the apartment number no one would have any idea where to deliver your pizza.

Comment: I havent made any change to my config file as such. And why would the internet company I am availing will make any difference and I am not sure how to check my router model.

Comment: `why would the internet company I am availing will make any difference` Many ISPs block some (or all) inbound connections for home users.

Comment: Different ISP's block different ports, so what is the point of trying to figure out why "Apache" is not working when the end result was "Your ISP" is blocking it. On another note some ISP's use NAT which would mean you will never be able to host your web server to the outside world.

Comment: Have you forwarded your ports?

Comment: No,  I was going to configure my router but I do not remember my login credentials. Will have to ask my flatmate in the morninng. I have one question though, let's say I forward the port 80 to say 81, now all the requests to my router will come to me, then what was stopping it for coming it to me before I made the changes?

Comment: @JonH Also, I guess I will have to change my apache to be working at the same port now, right? Some config changes there also?

Comment: @JonH Yeah, but I am still not sure why would i work for port 81 but not 80. Thanks

Comment: lets pretend that your WAN IP Address is 64.64.54.54. When you access a website or IP address in a web browser by default it is trying to access port 80 so when you tried to access (64.64.54.54) in the web browser in reality it is sending (64.64.54.54:80), to make this short this message finally arrives to your ISP and your ISP's router or firewall is saying "Nope, no port 80 is allowed on this network" and you get a Network Destination Unreachable.

Comment: @Jon H Thanks alot. Will try again tomorrow morning after the port forwarding.

Comment: @JonH Ok, One last thing, instead of changing my port from 80 to 81, I can just do a change from 80 to 80 itself right? That will tell the router to just forward and forget about the firewalls?

Another point being, If I change the apache's port from 80 to 81, then instead of doing any port forwarding, I can just do 64.64.54.54:81/index.html . Will this work?

Comment: @JonH Sorry, but one more thing, when I access some website, the response that comes back will be coming back to the same port 80 right? howcome in that case the router forwards that to my system? Does it differentiate somehow between a request and response, and it will only let all the responses come in and not the requests?

Comment: You dont want to use port 81 because that is used for onion routing, you want to use something like 8080.

Comment: Dont think I understand, chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47898/discussion-between-kraken-and-jon-h)

Comment: @JonH Basically I am just wondering, what is the difference between a normal HTTP traffic and the request to port 8080. Thanks.

Comment: @JonH Hi. I've got this another problem, if you could help.http://superuser.com/questions/793861/port-forwarding-to-make-my-localhost-available-for-everyone